# VueJS reactive Date object

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js, reactive-programming

Rather beginner question, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

I have 2 buttons that increment/decrement a given Date object by +/- 1 day. The object is updated, but the changes are not displayed. I found out it's because the Date Obj is not reactive, but I didn't find a solution or a workaround to this.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zacrdwfy/)

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="inc">+ 1 day</button>
  <button @click="dec">- 1 day</button>
  <br /><br />

  {{date}}
</div>
```

JS/Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    date: new Date()
  },
  methods: {
    inc () {
        this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1)
        console.log(this.date)
    },
    dec () {
        this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() - 1)
        console.log(this.date)
    }
  }
})
```

In the console the Date is incresed/decreased fine, but the date rendered on the page just stays the same. Can anybody help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are modifying the `date` object in place in which case Vue can not detect the changes, create a new date object instead:

https://jsfiddle.net/13gzu8xs/1/

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    date: new Date()
  },
  methods: {
    inc () {
      this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1)
      this.date = new Date(this.date)     //  create a new date and assign to this.date
        },
    dec () {
      this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() - 1)
      this.date = new Date(this.date)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Oooh, so simple. Thanks a lot, works like a charm and you saved me hours of trial & error